# Cypher: a node between two nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Austria is a part of `Western Europe`, which is part of `Europe`, which is part of the `World`.

`match (n:Country{iso_alpha_2:'AT'})-[PART_OF*]->(q:Geography)-[PART_OF*]->(w:Geography{name:'World'}) return q.name`

The query returns:

`q.name
Europe
Western Europe
World
World
Europe
Western Europe`

Why does it return duplicate rows? Additionally, how to return just a node one level down from `World` (in this case, just `Europe`)?

`match (n:Country{iso_alpha_2:'AT'})-[PART_OF*]->(q:Geography)-[PART_OF*1..1]->(w:Geography{name:'World'}) return q.name`

This attempt returns:

`q.name
Europe
World
World`

Comment: can you share your graph via http://console.neo4j.org?

Comment: @StefanArmbruster, I recreated from scratch here: http://console.neo4j.org/r/kkx8cc, and found the reason: `World` having `PART_OF` relationship to self in my database by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel,

This may depend on what version of Neo4j you are using, or on the form of your graph. I just used 2.1.3 to create the graph

```
(:Country {iso_alpha_2 : 'AT'})-[:PART_OF]->(:Geography {name : 'Western Europe'})-[:PART_OF]->(:Geography {name : 'Europe'})-[:PART_OF]->(:Geography {name : 'World'})
```

then ran your query. My result was

```
Europe
Western Europe
```

This makes me wonder if you don't have multiple paths from Austria to World.

To get a unique list, add the DISTINCT keyword to your return statement. To get just the element(s) one down from World, do the query

```
MATCH (n:Country{iso_alpha_2:'AT'})-[:PART_OF*]->(q:Geography)-[:PART_OF]->(w:Geography{name:'World'})      
RETURN DISTINCT q.name
```

Try this query with and without the DISTINCT keyword to see if you do in fact have multiple paths from Austria to World.

Grace and peace,

Jim

Comment: Jim, I've run your query and got `Type mismatch: PART_OF already defined with conflicting type Collection<Relationship> (expected Relationship) (line 1, column 64)
"MATCH (n:Country{iso_alpha_2:'AT'})-[PART_OF*]->(q:Geography)-[PART_OF]->(w:Geography{name:'World'})      "`

Comment: When testing: `MATCH (q:Geography{name:'World'})-[r:PART_OF]->(w:Geography{name:'World'}) RETURN r`
I found out that I indeed had `World` node pointing to self, which gave duplicate results. Case closed, thanks for fresh perspective!

Comment: Sorry about dropping the ':'s. I'll fix the answer.